# Python dict with duplicated keys or None

Tags: python

I have a class in python where I have a dict containing neighbors, and a list `pri_list` containing 21 instances of the class, but if I iterate over the neighbor,  I get duplicated keys or `None`.

```
print type(self.neighbors)
print str(self.id) + " " + str(self.neighbors)
print ""
for n in self.neighbors:
    print str(pri_list[n].id) + " " + str(pri_list[n].neighbors)
    pri_list[n].neighbors.update({self.id:self.neighbors[n]})
    print str(pri_list[n].id) + " " + str(pri_list[n].neighbors)
```

resulting in

```
<type 'dict'>
21 {22: 34.348765355132869, 23: 0, 19: 0.049076419727497315, 20: 36.087031068160286}

22 {21: 34.348765355132869, 23: 34.602568871995345, 8: 0.2351466696454737, 17: 0, 20: 0}
22 {21: 34.348765355132869, 23: 34.602568871995345, 8: 0.2351466696454737, 17: 0, 20: 0}
23 {21: 0, 22: 34.602568871995345, 8: 26.643673903936367, 17: 36.80385613689073}
23 {21: 0, 21: 0, 22: 34.602568871995345, 8: 26.643673903936367, 17: 36.80385613689073}
19 {21: 0.049076419727497315, 14: 0, 18: 41.407044987390677, 20: 39.517515427920443}
19 {21: 0.049076419727497315, 14: 0, 18: 41.407044987390677, 20: 39.517515427920443}
20 {21: 36.087031068160286, 22: 0, 18: 0.58414114578772669, 19: 39.517515427920443}
20 {21: 36.087031068160286, 22: 0, 18: 0.58414114578772669, 19: 39.517515427920443}
```

Observe how the key 21 occur twice in the id=23 dict after doing a update.

I have tried

```
pri_list[n].neighbors[self.id] = self.neighbors[n]
```

Giving the same result.

I Have tried it on two different machines which gave the same result.

I made a test example where I copied the data from the dict over as.

```
class A:
    neighbors = {}
    id = 0

    def __init__(self,id, neighbors):
        self.id = id
        self.neighbors = neighbors.copy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pri_list = [A(i, {})for i in range(0, 19)]

    pri_list.append(A(19, {21: 0.049076419727497315, 14: 0, 18: 41.407044987390677, 20: 39.517515427920443}))
    pri_list.append(A(20, {21: 36.087031068160286, 22: 0, 18: 0.58414114578772669, 19: 39.517515427920443}))
    pri_list.append(A(21, {22: 34.348765355132869, 23: 0, 19: 0.049076419727497315, 20: 36.087031068160286}))
    pri_list.append(A(22, {21: 34.348765355132869, 23: 34.602568871995345, 8: 0.2351466696454737, 17: 0, 20: 0}))
    pri_list.append(A(23, {21: 0, 22: 34.602568871995345, 8: 26.643673903936367, 17: 36.80385613689073}))

    print type(pri_list[21].neighbors)
    print str(pri_list[21].id) + " " + str(pri_list[21].neighbors)
    print ""

    for n in pri_list[21].neighbors:
        print str(pri_list[n].id) + " " + str(pri_list[n].neighbors)
        pri_list[n].neighbors.update({pri_list[21].id:pri_list[21].neighbors[n]})
        print str(pri_list[n].id) + " " + str(pri_list[n].neighbors)
```

This gave the expected result

```
<type 'dict'>
21 {22: 34.348765355132869, 23: 0, 19: 0.049076419727497315, 20:     36.087031068160286}

22 {8: 0.2351466696454737, 17: 0, 20: 0, 21: 34.348765355132869, 23: 34.602568871995345}
22 {8: 0.2351466696454737, 17: 0, 20: 0, 21: 34.348765355132869, 23: 34.602568871995345}
23 {21: 0, 22: 34.602568871995345, 8: 26.643673903936367, 17: 36.80385613689073}
23 {21: 0, 22: 34.602568871995345, 8: 26.643673903936367, 17: 36.80385613689073}
19 {21: 0.049076419727497315, 14: 0, 18: 41.407044987390677, 20: 39.517515427920443}
19 {21: 0.049076419727497315, 14: 0, 18: 41.407044987390677, 20: 39.517515427920443}
20 {21: 36.087031068160286, 22: 0, 18: 0.58414114578772669, 19: 39.517515427920443}
20 {21: 36.087031068160286, 22: 0, 18: 0.58414114578772669, 19: 39.517515427920443}
```

Observe how the key 21 occur only once in the `id=23` dict after doing an update, and the arrangement of the dict is also different.

I'm having a hard time even grasping how multiple keys can occur in the same dict, according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict this should not be possible

Comment: Can you print `print self.neighbors` a second time after the loop? My guess is that None is being added somewhere.

Comment: Aside: it would be very surprising if `len(poly_lines) < 0` ever did anything.

Comment: Ok I have boiled the problem dawn a bit se the end part of the problem

Comment: what is the type of `neighbors`? Is `self.neighbors` a `@property`?

Comment: The type is a dict, but using property is probly a good idea

Comment: Well, I did not mean to suggest using a property, but to track the bug.

Comment: So you can `print type(self.neighbors)` and get `<type 'dict'>` on your Python2.7 installation? Then your installation is buggy, because on my Python 2.7.9 here if I copy your dict at the bottom of the question into the REPL, then `print [n for n in _]`, I get `[0, 18, 21, 22]` as expected.

Comment: No changes if i print self.neighbors ones more as shown in the code above. At this moment I can add a check for None, but I am realy curios of how to add a None to a dist.

Comment: What is the output of type(self.neighbors) ?

Comment: I'd guess line `self.neighbors[n] += ...` is the problem.

Comment: print type(self.neighbors) = <type 'dict'>

Comment: I'm guessing that the `neighbors` dict for `pri_list[23]` has a key in it that looks like an integer without actually being one. Specifically, its `repr` is `"21"`, but its `hash` is not `hash(21)`. Can you try running `for key in pri_list[23].neighbors: print(key, type(key))`? Is one of the `21` keys not an integer? How were you producing those keys, in your original code?

Comment: Thanks that was a realy good idea, but unfortunately the output is all int (21, <type 'int'>)
(21, <type 'int'>)
(22, <type 'int'>)
(8, <type 'int'>)
(17, <type 'int'>)

Comment: How about `type(pri_list[23].neighbors)`?  And what is the `type` of the _values_ in that (presumed) dictionary?

Comment: Does your code update the dictionary while iterating over it? Then it's undefined whether you see a key once, twice or not at all, and you need to iterate in some other way. I can think of two, but they are not equal.

Comment: How are you constructing neighbors initially? Is it possible that you're doing a shallow copy somewhere and then one or more nodes actually start out with the same dictionary? If so, the update could modify the dictionary that's being iterated over, which would cause trouble. To better understand the nature of the problem, you could dump `pri_list` as `yaml` and see if there are any unexpected references, i.e. shared objects.

Comment: I just realized I commented a three year old question...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you provided is that you **update** the dictionary **while iterating** through it. I am not 100% sure that this is the cause, but generally it is a bad idea and it does lead to unpredictable results. Just make a copy to iterate through.